# IE10 printing footer (sticky note) only in the last page

Tags: css, footer, internet-explorer-10, sticky

I am totally stuck up with a strange issue in printing a footer at the end of the document in IE10. I have followed a similar approach to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737743/css-how-to-force-child-to-use-parent-height-in-sticky-footer. It prints correctly in all IE versions including IE10. However IE10 does not honour the absolute CSS positioning of footer and shows the footer immediately after the content. My actual code sample is as follows.

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}

p {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom:100px;
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

@media print {
    /*For FF to fix the printing issue.*/
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        #footer {
            position: relative;
        }
    }

    /*Chrome*/
    @media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        #footer {
            position:relative;
        }
    }
```

content goes here
        
        
            sample footer

I would really appreciate if anyone put some light on this issue as it takes me for a spin.